# Recoding the id column row ids to the name of each dataframe to achieve individual rownames for a table in R

Tags: r

I got the following code that a user here helped me with:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # pivot_wider
library(purrr) # map_dfr

test_df <- data.frame(old_cat = c("A_Old","B_Old","C_Old","D_Old","E_Old","J_Old","Y_Old"),section = c("A1","A1","A3","A2","A3","A1","A3"))
test_df2 <- data.frame(old_cat = c("D_Old","J_Old","Y_Old"), section = c("A1","A1","A1"))
test_df3 <- data.frame(old_cat = c("A_Old","A_Old","A_Old"),section =c("A1","A2","A3"))


split_test_df <- list_section <- split(test_df, test_df$section)
split_test_df2 <- list_section <- split(test_df2, test_df2$section)
split_test_df3 <- list_section <- split(test_df3, test_df3$section)

  
  generals <- list(test_df,test_df2,test_df3)
  subsection <- c(split_test_df,split_test_df2,split_test_df3)
  appended_list <- append(generals,subsection)

conversions <- tibble(
  old_cat = c("A_Old","B_Old","C_Old","D_Old","E_Old","J_Old","Y_Old"),
  new_cat = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "Other", "Other")
)



table <- appended_list %>%
  map_dfr(., ~ left_join(., conversions, by = "old_cat") %>%
               group_by(new_cat) %>%
               tally(),
          .id = "id")
```

Basically, I have a 5,000 row data frame. This data frame is then filtered into multiple data frames that are then created into the "test_df" that you see in the above example (there will be other data frames filtered out from the original but they will be too many to give for this example). These test data frames are then filtered as I want (test_df ("General"), test_df2("Filtered_one_way1") and test_df3("filtered_the_other_way") will always be called the same).  Essentially, I make each data frame a row in a final output table by running this code piped to the table that you see at the end of my example `%>% pivot_wider(id, names_from = new_cat, values_from = n,values_fill = list(n = 0L))` . My goal here is for each row (in the example it's the id column) to correspond to the name of each data frame and category name for subsection, this is where it gets tricky.

The split_test_df that you see above, are these filtered out data frames split into the section categories, these are then put into a list per section and the total number of sections will vary depending on the original filtered dataframe. The point of this is to have a row for the total number of n per section. This is an example of how my row should look, row 1 = "General" (This one will always be called this), row 2 = "A1" , row 3 = "A2", row 4 "A3". I was able to successfully do this with `mutate(id = recode(id,` 1`= "General",`2 `= "A1",`3 `= "A2",`4 `= "A3",`5 `= "Filtered even more Category))` . This would work well if all of other filtered out dataframes had the same number of sections but this is not the case (some will have section =c("A1","A2","A3") as the example above, but others with have section =c("A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A22"), section =c("B1","B2"), etc.) In the end there's no way for me to give a correct recode since the total number of sections will be different per filtered out data frame. To recap this is how I want my results to look like:

```
Filtered out data frame 1
id       | A | B | C | Other
General  | n | n | n | n
A1       | n | n | n | n
A2       | n | n | n | n
A3       | n | n | n | n
Filtered 
_one_way1| n | n | n | n
A1       | n | n | n | n
Filtered_
the_other
_way     | n | n | n | n
A1       | n | n | n | n
A2       | n | n | n | n
A3       | n | n | n | n 
A4       | n | n | n | n 

Filtered data frame 2 

id       | A | B | C | Other
General  | n | n | n | n
A1       | n | n | n | n
A2       | n | n | n | n
A3       | n | n | n | n
Filtered 
_one_way1| n | n | n | n
A1       | n | n | n | n
A2       | n | n | n | n
Filtered_
the_other
_way     | n | n | n | n
A1       | n | n | n | n
A3       | n | n | n | n 

Filtered data frame 3

id       | A | B | C | Other
General  | n | n | n | n
B1       | n | n | n | n
B2       | n | n | n | n
Filtered 
_one_way1| n | n | n | n
B1       | n | n | n | n
B2       | n | n | n | n
Filtered_
the_other
_way     | n | n | n | n
B2       | n | n | n | n
```

Is there a way to achieve this in R? I'm hoping this made sense. Thank you!

Comment: I had a small breakthrough, using the names(appended_list) function, extracts the names so essentially I want to get those names and apply them to the id column,

Comment: In the row names, what is `Filtered_
the_other` etc.

Comment: Not entirely clear about the expected.  May be `bind_rows(c(setNames(generals, rep('General', length(generals))), subsection), .id = 'grp') %>% left_join(conversions, by = 'old_cat') %>% select(-old_cat, -section) %>% count(grp, new_cat) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = new_cat, values_from = n)`

Comment: Or it could be `bind_rows(c(setNames(generals, rep('General', length(generals))), subsection), .id = 'grp') %>% left_join(conversions, by = 'old_cat') %>% select(-old_cat) %>% count(grp, section, new_cat) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = new_cat, values_from = n) %>% group_split(section, keep = FALSE)`